# Slideshow - css jquery

Tags: jquery, css, slider, carousel, slideshow

**I need like this slide any help please**

[This is my slideshow looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDWsd.png)

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (the JavaScript code using jQuery), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap carousel or you can find an slideshow example on w3school, then you can style it on your own.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

If you want to make it quick, you can download WOWSlider software and choose the style of slideshow as you want : http://wowslider.com/

Try to do it first, then if you have any problem while making it, you can post your issue here for help.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i know how to use carousel bootstrap but the problem is how can i do the navigation with images and style them left and right :((